# Closed form of the power series of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin(n)\,x^n$ (Mathematica)

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

It's not hard to show that the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin(n)\,x^n$ is $1$, however I'm at a loss for finding a closed form of the series... although Mathematica seems to have no trouble whatsoever:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin(n)\,x^n =  \frac{-ix(e^{2i}-1)}{2(x-e^{i})(e^{i}x-1)} \\
$$
$$
= \frac{x \sin(1)}{1 + x^2 - 2 x \cos(1)}
$$

which oddly enough is real-valued, after simplifying a bit with Mathematica.

How would one go about finding this? I couldn't believe that Mathematica had such an easy time with the series, let alone that there was an actual closed form.

Comment: Write the sine in the exponential way, and then use Geometric Series.

Comment: Similarly you may write the Taylor summation formula for sine and then multiply each term by it's corresponding $x^n$ term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (e^{i}x)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{in}\,x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos(n)\,x^n+i\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin(n)\,x^n$$

Comment: Thanks! That is quite a clever solution!